# Syntax Error in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This my <strike>pl/sql</strike> PL/pgSQL function. I am facing syntax error in this function. Can you please help me to solve this problem.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$2"
LINE 1: SELECT   $1  FOR  $2  IN(select abl.ka003_position_lk_id as ...
                          ^
QUERY:  SELECT   $1  FOR  $2  IN(select abl.ka003_position_lk_id as posit, sum(abl.nooflabors*abl.hours) as totalhours from ahcc_boq_labor abl where ahcc_boq_item_id= $3  group by abl.ka003_position_lk_id) LOOP  $4  =  $5 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "ahcc_proj_budget_cpy_plan1" near line 83

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
SQL state: 42601
Context: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "ahcc_proj_budget_cpy_plan1" near line 83
```

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ahcc_proj_budget_cpy_plan1(p_pinstance_id character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$ DECLARE 
v_Process CHAR(1);
v_project_id VARCHAR(32);
v_projbudget VARCHAR(32);
v_client VARCHAR(32);
v_petty NUMERIC;
v_org VARCHAR(32);
v_mrl NUMERIC;
v_hr NUMERIC;
v_eqp NUMERIC;
v_createdby VARCHAR(32);
v_updatedby VARCHAR(32);
v_record_id VARCHAR(32); 
v_ResultStr VARCHAR(120);
v_status VARCHAR(32);
v_message VARCHAR(255);
v_userid VARCHAR(32);
v_wbs_id VARCHAR(32);
v_boq_id VARCHAR(32);
v_boqitem_id VARCHAR(32);
v_positionId VARCHAR(255);
v_totalhours VARCHAR(255);
v_mproduct_id VARCHAR(255);
v_quantity VARCHAR(255);
v_hours VARCHAR(255);
v_material VARCHAR(255);
v_mquantity VARCHAR(255);
Cur_boq RECORD;
Cur_wbs RECORD;
Cur_hr RECORD;
Cur_eqp RECORD;
Cur_mrl RECORD;
  BEGIN

   --  Update AD_PInstance by setting IsProcessing='Y'
    RAISE NOTICE '%','Updating PInstance - Processing ' || p_PInstance_ID ;
    PERFORM AD_UPDATE_PINSTANCE(p_PInstance_ID, NULL, 'Y', NULL, NULL) ;
    BEGIN 
    select record_id,ad_user_id into v_record_id,v_userid from ad_pinstance where ad_pinstance_id=p_PInstance_ID;
    select ahcc_project_id,ahcc_proj_budget_id, AD_CLIENT_ID, AD_ORG_ID,
             CREATEDBY, UPDATEDBY,process 
             into v_project_id,v_projbudget,v_client,v_org,v_createdby,v_updatedby,v_process
              from ahcc_proj_budget where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_Record_ID;
                        update ahcc_proj_budget set process='N' where Process='Y';

            select count(*) into v_mrl from ahcc_proj_budget_mrl where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;
            select count(*) into v_hr from ahcc_proj_budget_hr where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;
            select count(*) into v_eqp from ahcc_proj_budget_eqp where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;

              IF (v_mrl<>0 OR v_hr<>0 OR v_eqp<>0) THEN
                  delete from  ahcc_proj_budget_mrl where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;
                  delete from ahcc_proj_budget_hr where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;
                  delete from ahcc_proj_budget_eqp where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;
              END IF;

            select count(*) into v_mrl from ahcc_proj_budget_mrl where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;
            select count(*) into v_hr from ahcc_proj_budget_hr where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;
            select count(*) into v_eqp from ahcc_proj_budget_eqp where ahcc_proj_budget_id=v_record_id;


               IF (v_mrl=0 AND v_hr=0 AND v_eqp=0) THEN
        FOR Cur_wbs IN (select apwbs.ahcc_project_wbs_id  , apbi.ahcc_boq_item_id
                from ahcc_project_boqitem apbi
                left join (select ahcc_project_wbs_id from ahcc_project_wbs
                where ahcc_project_wbs_id not in(select wbs_parent_id from ahcc_project_wbs) 
                and ahcc_project_id=v_project_id) apwbs 
                on apbi.ahcc_project_wbs_id=apwbs.ahcc_project_wbs_id)
        LOOP
                v_wbs_id = Cur_wbs.apwbs.ahcc_project_wbs_id;
                v_boq_id = Cur_wbs.apbi.ahcc_boq_item_id;

            FOR Cur_boq IN(SELECT ahcc_boq_item_id  FROM connectby('ahcc_boq_item','ahcc_boq_item_id',
                'boqitem_parentid','boqitem_name',v_boq_id,0 ,'/') AS 
                t(ahcc_boq_item_id text, boqc_parentid text, level int, branch text ,pos int))
            LOOP    
                v_boqitem_id = Cur_boq.ahcc_boq_item_id

                FOR Cur_hr IN(select abl.ka003_position_lk_id as posit, sum(abl.nooflabors*abl.hours) as totalhours 
                    from ahcc_boq_labor abl
                    where ahcc_boq_item_id=v_boqitem_id
                    group by abl.ka003_position_lk_id)
                LOOP
                    v_positionId = Cur_hr.posit;
                    v_totalhours = Cur_hr.totalhours;

                    INSERT INTO AHCC_Proj_budget_hr
                     (
                        AHCC_Proj_budget_hr_ID,ahcc_proj_budget_id, AD_CLIENT_ID, AD_ORG_ID, ISACTIVE,
                        CREATED, CREATEDBY, UPDATED, UPDATEDBY,ka003_position_lk_id,hourprice,totalprice,total_hour)
                     VALUES
                     (
                        GET_UUID(),v_projbudget,v_client,v_org,'Y',TO_DATE(NOW()),v_createdby,TO_DATE(NOW()),v_updatedby,
                        v_positionId,0,0,v_totalhours
                     );
                END LOOP;
                FOR Cur_eqp IN(select abe.m_product_id as product,sum(abe.equipment_quantity) as qty,sum(abe.noofhours) as hour
                        from ahcc_boq_equipment abe where ahcc_boq_item_id=v_boqitem_id
                        group by abe.m_product_id)

                LOOP
                    v_mproduct_id = Cur_eqp.m_product_id;
                    v_quantity = Cur_eqp.qty;
                    v_hours = Cur_eqp.hour;


                    INSERT INTO AHCC_Proj_budget_eqp
                    (
                       AHCC_Proj_budget_eqp_ID,ahcc_proj_budget_id, AD_CLIENT_ID, AD_ORG_ID, ISACTIVE,
                       CREATED, CREATEDBY, UPDATED, UPDATEDBY,m_product_id,no_of_equipment,hour,hourprice,totalprice)
                    VALUES
                    (
                       GET_UUID(),v_projbudget,v_client,v_org,'Y',TO_DATE(NOW()),v_createdby,TO_DATE(NOW()),v_updatedby,
                       v_mproduct_id,v_quantity,v_hours,0,0
                    );
                END LOOP;

                FOR Cur_mrl IN(select abm.m_product_id, sum(abm.material_quantity) as qty from ahcc_boq_material abm
                        where ahcc_boq_item_id=v_boqitem_id
                        group by abm.m_product_id)
                LOOP
                    v_material = Cur_mrl.m_product_id;
                    v_mquantity = Cur_mrl.qty;

                    INSERT INTO AHCC_Proj_budget_mrl
                    (
                      AHCC_Proj_budget_mrl_ID,ahcc_proj_budget_id, AD_CLIENT_ID, AD_ORG_ID, ISACTIVE,
                      CREATED, CREATEDBY, UPDATED, UPDATEDBY,m_product_id,quantity,productprice,totalprice)
                    VALUES              
                    (
                      GET_UUID(),v_projbudget,v_client,v_org,'Y',TO_DATE(NOW()),v_createdby,TO_DATE(NOW()),v_updatedby,
                      v_material,v_mquantity,0,0
                    );

                END LOOP;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;   

          END IF;

    RAISE NOTICE '%','Updating PInstance - Finished ' || v_Message ;
 PERFORM AD_UPDATE_PINSTANCE(p_PInstance_ID, NULL, 'N', 1, v_Message) ;    
    RETURN;
 END; -- BODY

 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   v_ResultStr:= '@ERROR=' || SQLERRM;
   RAISE NOTICE '%',v_ResultStr ;
   PERFORM AD_UPDATE_PINSTANCE(p_PInstance_ID, NULL, 'N', 0, v_ResultStr) ;
   RETURN;
END ; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION ahcc_proj_budget_cpy_plan1(character varying) OWNER TO tad;
```

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this. In this case Krtek formatted your code for you, but try it yourself in the future. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: Rather than posting the entirety of your code as a sample, you should always post a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/), which is just enough code to reproduce the problem (but no more).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Add a semicolon just before line 83

Like so:

```
v_boqitem_id = Cur_boq.ahcc_boq_item_id;
```